# Graph with percent change between periods in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I have an index with Elasticsearch which contains (inter alia) year and weight fields. In Kibana (v5), I can easily produce a bar chart presenting the sum of all weights for each year:
[image]

How can I construct a bar chart, that will present how the total weight has changed since previous year? So the formula (in meta-language) will be like: `sum(weight[year])/sum(weight[year-1])`. There are [**pipeline aggregations**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) in Elastic, but I cannot find a way to calculate the bucket to bucket percent change?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to achieve the goal using Timelion, which recently became native Kibana module. Timelion allows to perform math operations between series, including setting offset on the time (x) axis.

In order to calculate the fraction between buckets, I have used the following formula:

```
.es(index=myindex,timefield=year_date,metric=sum:weight).divide(.es(index=myindex,timefield=year_date,metric=sum:weight,offset=-1y)).multiply(100).subtract(100).bars()
```

The crucial part is here to `.divide` series by the same data with `.offset(-1y)`.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful! But I have a different use case. Let's say I have the following query: `.es(index=bk_random3_appended,timefield=Time,metric=count,q=170863).subtract(.es(index=bk_random3_appended,timefield=Time,metric=count,q=170868))` . But I want the query to be dynamically generated. Say, I select values '170865' & '170866' in the dashboard, I want the query to read :  'q=170865' subtracted by 'q=170866', i.e. the Lucene query will dynamically take values from dashboard filter.. Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting use case! I do not know how to solve it in Timelion, I have now moved away of Kibana and dynamically generate queries to ES and visualize in Angular.